# Settings: Tap to Click?

Tags: trackpad

My computer's battery was getting too old so I sent my macbook to an unofficial A/S center. After a week, I got my macbook back and my trackpad felt a bit wrong. It was moving and clicking like it was supposed to, but it wasn't making any of those satisfying 'click!' sound. In the settings>trackpad>point&click section, "Tap to Click" isn't even on. What do I do?

Comment: Sending it back for repair might be the best course of action.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks! I actually did send it back to fix the trackpad - they used a bigger battery thing(how do you call that? Internal battery?) so they removed something under the trackpad (that's what they say so).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Trackpad > Point & Click and than enable "Tap to Click" and disable "Silent Clicking".

Answer (score -1):

Maybe turn on "Tap to Click" on?

Comment: But I thought "Tap to Click" made it even more silent and stuff...